# Where are the downloaded apps on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

I have a new Windows 8 machine and I can't locate the apps I have downloaded from the store.

Comment: On the start screen there should be an arrow in the bottom left. click it and all your apps will appear. If you have a touchscreen just swipe up on the start screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed an app from the Store or from an installer, it will appear in your Start screen under the Apps view.

Click the little arrow on the bottom left of the Start screen to open the list of all apps:

[image]

You can sort this list by most recently installed to quickly see the app you just installed at the top.

[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/getting-around-tutorial) is a nice page for several navigation tips for Windows 8, from which I got the above info.